# named or called when creating new files

Tags: word-usage, difference

I understand that *called* is more common than *named*. In some websites (including Universities websites) that I have looked over, is used *called* as well as *named* when you're referring to create a new file (in a project or in any Operating System). What's more common to use when you're creating, for instance, a technical article/paper?

Comment: My software programmes permit me to **rename** a file or folder. I am not a techie but I'd opt for **naming** rather than calling.

Comment: It really makes a lot of sense to use in this way